# VBA in access...IF THEN ELSE

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a conditional statement that will basically say if field1 + field2 = "string" then do some stuff... i am pretty sure i have the stuff part right but i dont think i have the conditional statement correct... this is what i have

```
txtTeam.Visible = True
If ([GuestFirstName] + [GuestLastName] = "Angela Cockrill") Then
    [LifetimeTxt] = "Trips of a Lifetime!"
    txtTeam.ForeColor = vbOrange
    txtTeam.FontSize = 14
    txtTeam.FontBold = True

Else
    txtTeam.Visible = False
    txtTeam.ForeColor = 0

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access VBA I would use the ampersand operator & to concatenate 2 strings together, not the plus sign but that's just a preference. You also may need to account for the space e.g.

```
txtTeam.Visible = True
If ([GuestFirstName] & " " & [GuestLastName] = "Angela Cockrill") Then
    [LifetimeTxt] = "Trips of a Lifetime!"
    txtTeam.ForeColor = vbOrange
    txtTeam.FontSize = 14
    txtTeam.FontBold = True

Else
    txtTeam.Visible = False
    txtTeam.ForeColor = 0

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have in your fields you probably need to add the space, as well as use ampersands:

`If ([GuestFirstName] & " " & [GuestLastName] = "Angela Cockrill") Then`